# How to write a Perl Script to find a string in a file?

Tags: scripting, perl

I want to write a Perl script to find the variable if present in the TEST titles only, not in the FIRST, SECOND or THIRD titles. So there are N number of variables in a files before the TEST titles; But I want to match the variables after the TEST titles. If the TEST title doesn't have the variable need to print `variable not exist in first TEST` (or *Second TEST* or *Third TEST*).

I have a file like below.

```
FIRST
there is a variable one

SECOND
there is second variable

THIRD
there is third variable

FOUR
xxx
xxx

FIVE
variable
xxx

TEST1
firstline 001
secondline 002
thirdvariable line 003

TEST2
firstline 001
secondline 002
thirdline 003

TEST3
firstline 001
secondline 002
thirdvariable line 003
```

Comment: Why only Perl? You are not interested with `awk` :  ) also would you please let us know what have you tried?

Comment: If you know the perl uu can give the answer

Comment: So what do you have so far? Which part is giving you trouble? You need to do some of the work here too. What output do you expect from the example you gave us? Will the actual words `FIRST`, `FOUR` etc? Be there? How come you have first, second and third but then have `four` and not `fourth`? Will there always be a single empty line between the sections? How do we find the "variable"? What variable? How do we recognize it? We can't help you unless you give us enough information to understand what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk` for this (since I know `awk` fun!).

```
awk -vRS='TEST[[:digit:]]' 'BEGIN{rs=RS} NF>1 && $1 ~ rs{ print $1":";$1=""; print $0;}
    NF==1{print "variable not exist in: "$1}' RS='' infile
```

This will give you output like below for your given sample data.

```
TEST1:
 firstline 001 secondline 002 thirdvariable line 003
TEST2:
 firstline 001 secondline 002 thirdline 003
TEST3:
 firstline 001 secondline 002 thirdvariable line 003
variable not exist in: TEST4
variable not exist in: TEST5
```